# Remove language from URL in Next JS dynamic routes

Tags: next.js, next-i18next

I have a website in NextJS with next-i18next, and every page must be translated except for the `legal` pages.

These `legal` pages are in markdown, and I have dynamic routing enabled thanks to a `[legal].js` page and the `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` in it.

The problem is that by building my website, my legal pages are prefixed with the language (here `en`). I would like to remove it as I don't want these pages to be translated.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot

Folder structure:

```
pages
|- index.js
|- [legal].js
|- privacy-policy.mdx
```

next-i18next.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en'],
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    defaultNS: ['homepage', 'header', 'footer'],
    localeDetection: false,
  },
}
```

[legal].js

```js
import matter from 'gray-matter'
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations'
import glob from 'glob'

const LegalPage = ({ markdownBody }) => (
  <ReactMarkdown>{markdownBody}</ReactMarkdown>
)

export async function getStaticProps({ locale, params }) {
  const { legal } = params
  const content = await import(`./${legal}.mdx`)
  const data = matter(content.default)

  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['header', 'footer'])),
      markdownBody: data.content,
    },
  }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const blogs = glob.sync('src/pages/**/*.mdx')

  const blogSlugs = blogs.map(file => {
    const parts = file.split('/')
    return parts[parts.length - 1].replace('.mdx', '')
  })

  const paths = blogSlugs.map(slug => ({
    params: { legal: slug },
  }))

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  }
}

export default LegalPage
```

build output:

[image: output-with_language_in_dynamic_pages]

Comment: You're only generating the `en` version of the `privacy-policy` page anyway. Do you simply not want users to access `/en/privacy-policy` in the browser? If so, you can use a redirect to `/privacy-policy`.

Comment: @juliomalves what we want is a proper HTML version of the page without any locale in the URL. In this case `/privacy-policy`

Answer (score 0):

All static HTML files should be created in separate folders for each locale.
Your default locale can be omitted in the URL, and the following URLs are equivalent:

```
example.com/my-first-blog
example.com/en/my-first-blog
```

As a solution, you can setup app i18n base on domain:

```js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    domains: [
      {
        domain: 'example.com',
        defaultLocale: 'en',
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Indeed, the pages with and without the `/en/` are equivalent, but for SEO purposes, I would prefer having only the one without the `/en/` prefix.

My slugs don't have any prefixes so the problem doesn't come from there. 
And I can't remove the `serverSideTranslations` as I need them for my Header and Footer translations  But I tested removing it, and it also didn't fixed the problem.

Comment: @mdubus did you find any fix for this? I am facing the same issue